# Error reading .msg files with extract-msg package

Tags: python, email, msg

I am receiving an error while running extract-msg package:

"Current version of extract_msg does not support extraction of containers that are not embedded msg files."

I am reading in a folder that contains only .msg files, any idea on how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: could you please descripe your problem in more detail, with code example what you have tried ?

Comment: What types of attachments do you have? The error message is specific, but opaque if you don’t know about how msg files handle attachments. The extract_msg package can handle simple attachments (txt, pdf, etc), and msg files, but not other container attachments.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the place where the error is raised (https://github.com/mattgwwalker/msg-extractor/blob/6fd92d74562425e79487fba56c5e1ae5caaf6681/extract_msg/attachment.py#L47) and it seems to be related to attachment data. I feel like it might be that the library might not be able to handle extracting attachments other than other attached email messages (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).

## Coarse-grained solution

A possible solution is wrapping your message extraction code in a try/catch block to ignore the attachment (if that's alright).

```
# Example
for message in messages:
    try:
        # Extract message using extract_msg
    catch NotImplementedError:
        print("Failed to extract message")
```

That way it will just skip over those messages that it fails to extract the attachments of.

## Fine-grained solution

For just skipping attachments while still parsing the rest of the message, you could open `message.py` in `extract_msg` and change lines 502-503 to read as follows:

```
for attachmentDir in attachmentDirs:
    try:
        self._attachments.append(self.__attachmentClass(self, attachmentDir))
    catch NotImplementedError:
        print("Failed to extract attachment")
```

That way at least the message and valid attachments will be parsed, but the problematic attachments will be skipped.

I'd look into whether there are ways to ignore the parsing of attachments if the attachment data is not crucial to your purposes. Alternatively, `extract_msg` allows you to specify a custom class to handle the processing of attachments, so you could look into that as well. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, so I have implemented the try and catch block however I am losing about 10% of my emails. My guess is that these emails being skipped are emails with attachments. Any way to still get the content of these emails while ignoring its attachments?

Comment: Yep, you can take a look at the fine-grained solution instead :)